# Android: Draggable view to show another view (similar to Facebook)

Tags: android, facebook, draggable, android-linearlayout

For those of you who have used the Facebook app, it has an interesting way of showing more information on the home activity by having a draggable view at the bottom of the screen that, when dragged up, shows Facebook notifications.  Dragging the same view back down hides the notifications.  Note that this will work either by holding and dragging it to the top of the screen or simply flinging it in that direction.

I would like to do something similar for my app.  I have a LinearLayout at the bottom of my activity and want to be able to drag it up to see more information.  How can I go about doing this?  Are there any tutorials available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out the sliding drawer component? 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html

I think this might be what you are looking for.